# Docked footer that acts like a frame?

Tags: javascript, html, frames, audio-player

I'm designing a band website and Reverbnation has a cool music player in the footer which allows music to keep playing while changing pages.

I've looked at the code and I can't see any evidence of using frames. Which is the only way I know of achieving something like this. But that way is no longer supported in HTML5 and is also crap for SEO.

There is some JavaScript in the source code of the player, but I don't know enough JavaScript to tell if it's responsible. Something like this would be very useful to the site I'm building.

I would try a Google search but I have no idea what keywords I would use to look for a how to on the subject.

As the code was pretty long I cut and paste it here if anybody is willing to take a look at it.

Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {

    if (!$("body").hasClass("new_sofia_navigation")) {
      $("body").addClass("new_sofia_navigation")
    }

    var $search_el = $('#sofia_header_search input[type=text]')
    $search_el.quickSearch({
      search_path: 'http://search.reverbnation.com/search/quick.json',
      use_jsonp: true
    });


    $("#sofia_header_search").submit(function(e) {
      var $form = $(this);
      e.preventDefault();
      Reverb.Navigate.go_to_page_url($form.attr('action') + '?' + $form.serialize());
    });

    var repositionSearchContainer = function() {
      $("#global_menu_search").find(".expanded_content").alignTo($("#global_menu_search"), "br-tr")
    }

    $("#menu_notifications, #global_menu_search, #menu_user_actions").bind("expand", function() {
      var $menu = $(this).find(".expanded_content"),
        $align_target = $("#global_menu_search"),
        align_offset = {
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }
      if ($menu.hasAttr("data-align-target")) {
        $align_target = $("#" + $menu.attr("data-align-target"))
      }
      if ($menu.hasAttr("data-align-offset")) {
        var offsets = $menu.attr("data-align-offset").split(":")
        align_offset.left = parseInt(offsets[0]) || 0
        align_offset.top = parseInt(offsets[1]) || 0
      }
      $(this).find(".expanded_content").alignTo($align_target, "br-tr", align_offset)
    })

    $search_el.bind("quicksearch_disable", repositionSearchContainer).bind("quicksearch_enable", repositionSearchContainer)
    $("#menu_notifications:not(.no_notices)").bind("expand", function() {
      $.get("/page_object/reset_new_notice_count/artist_332065")
      $(this).addClass("no_notices")
    })

    $(window).trigger('user:login', {
      "type": "Artist",
      "feat_ownapp_apple": "0",
      "artist_bes": 5722,
      "feat_rpk": "P",
      "feat_fr_rap": "P",
      "feat_ownapp_push": "0",
      "feat_mega": "0",
      "feat_distro": "0",
      "feat_ownapp": "0",
      "feat_distro_p": "0",
      "feat_distro_e": "0",
      "is_admin": false,
      "feat_widg": "0",
      "feat_mega_max": "0",
      "artist_country": "UK",
      "genre": "Metal",
      "feat_fr": "P",
      "feat_bundle": "0",
      "feat_ownapp_droid": "0",
      "artist_bought": true,
      "control_room": "sofia",
      "name": "Soul Sanctuary",
      "id": 332065,
      "feat_sb": "0",
      "feat_fr_360": "0",
      "current_layout": "v3"
    });

  });
</script>

</div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    Reverb.Notification.init('#standard_flash_message');
  });
</script>

</div>
<div id="docked_footer">
  <style type="text/css">
    #sm2-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 1px;
      height: 1px;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="loading_gif">
    <img alt="16x16_black" src="http://gp1.wac.edgecastcdn.net/802892/production_static/images/spinners/16x16_black.gif?1357641892" />
    <span>Loading...</span>
  </div>

  <textarea id="template" style="display:none">
  <div class="player_queue_item" >
    <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Toggle Item');" class="toggle"></a>
    <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Remove Item');" class="remove" data-command="remove_song"></a>
    <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Play Item ');" class="play_state" data-command="play" ></a>
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <div class="content">
        <a href='{link}'><img src='{image}' /></a>
        <h3 title="{title}">{title_display}</h3>
        <a href='{link}'><h4 title="{artist}">{artist_display}</h4></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions" style="text-align:center">
      <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Download Button');" class="first" data-command="download">Download</a>
      <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Share Button');" data-command="share">Share</a>
      <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Favorite Button');" data-command="favorite">Favorite</a>
      <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Lyrics Button');" data-command="lyrics">Lyrics</a>
      <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Become Fan Button');" data-command="fan" class="last">Be a fan</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</textarea>

  <div id="sm2-container"></div>

  <div class="footer_content clearfix">
    <div class="footer_music_player" id="music_player">

      <div class="player_queue collapsed" id="player_queue">
        <div class="player_queue_content">
          <div class="player_queue_header">
            <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Collapse Queue');" data-command="toggle" class="collapse"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="player_queue_items card" data-card="queue_items">
            <div class="card_actions clearfix">
              <span data-role="title"></span>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Clear Queue');" data-command="clear_playlist" class="playlist_action">Clear</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Share All');" data-command="share_playlist" class="playlist_action">Share All</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Show Channels');" data-command="show_discover" class="playlist_action">Channels</a>
            </div>
            <div class="player_queue_list"></div>
          </div>

          <div class=" card" data-card="queue_discover">
            <div class="card_actions">
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Show Queue');" data-command="show_playlist" class="discovery_action">Show Queue</a>
            </div>
            <div class="player_queue_discover">
              <h1>ReverbNation Channels</h1>
              <h3>Select a Music Channel to Get Started</h3>

              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Global Chart Toppers');" data-command="discover_global">Global Chart Toppers</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Local Chart Toppers');" data-command="discover_local">Local Chart Toppers</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Trending Artists');" data-command="discover_trending">Trending Artists</a>

              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Alt/Rock/Indie');" data-command="discover_alt_rock_indie">Alt/Rock/Indie</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Electro/Pop/Dance');" data-command="discover_electro_pop_dance">Electro/Pop/Dance</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','HipHop/Rap/RB');" data-command="discover_hiphop_rap_rbsoul">HipHop/Rap/R&amp;B</a>

              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Featured Artists');" data-command="discover_featured">Featured Artists</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','My Favorites');" data-command="discover_my_favorites">My Favorites</a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Custom Channel');" data-command="discover_custom_channel">Custom Channel</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="player_queue_custom_channel card" data-card="queue_custom_channel">
            <div class="card_actions">
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Show Queue');" data-command="show_playlist" class="discovery_action">Show Queue</a>
            </div>
            <form action="/c/audio_player/music_now" id="custom_channel_form" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/c/audio_player/music_now', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;"> <label for="reverb_radio_genres_player_select">Select Genres:</label>
              <input id="reverb_radio_channel" name="reverb_radio[channel]" type="hidden" value="reverb_picks" />
              <select data-placeholder="Click to select genre(s)" id="reverb_radio_genres_player_select" multiple="multiple" name="reverb_radio[genres][]">
                <option value="alternative">Alternative</option>
                <option value="ambient">Ambient</option>
                <option value="americana">Americana</option>
                <option value="bluegrass">Bluegrass</option>
                <option value="blues">Blues</option>
                <option value="bollywoodtollywood">Bollywood/Tollywood</option>
                <option value="celtic">Celtic</option>
                <option value="childrens">Childrens</option>
                <option value="christianrock">Christian Rock</option>
                <option value="christiangospel">Christian/Gospel</option>
                <option value="classical">Classical</option>
                <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
                <option value="country">Country</option>
                <option value="dj">DJ</option>
                <option value="dance">Dance</option>
                <option value="dubstep">Dubstep</option>
                <option value="electronicdancemusic">Electronic Dance Music</option>
                <option value="electronica">Electronica</option>
                <option value="experimental">Experimental</option>
                <option value="folk">Folk</option>
                <option value="funk">Funk</option>
                <option value="hiphop">Hip Hop</option>
                <option value="holiday">Holiday</option>
                <option value="house">House</option>
                <option value="indie">Indie</option>
                <option value="instrumental">Instrumental</option>
                <option value="jam">Jam</option>
                <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
                <option value="latin">Latin</option>
                <option value="metal">Metal</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
                <option value="pop">Pop</option>
                <option value="punk">Punk</option>
                <option value="rbsoul">R&amp;B/Soul</option>
                <option value="rap">Rap</option>
                <option value="reggae">Reggae</option>
                <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                <option value="rockabilly">Rockabilly</option>
                <option value="singersongwriter">Singer Songwriter</option>
                <option value="ska">Ska</option>
                <option value="spiritual">Spiritual</option>
                <option value="spokenword">Spoken Word</option>
                <option value="world">World</option>
              </select>
              <input class="standard_button style_primary size_small" name="commit" type="submit" value="Ok" />
              <a href="javascript:;" data-command="back">Cancel</a>
            </form>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="player_about" id="player_about">

        <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Toggle Playlist');" class="toggle_playlist" data-command="toggle_playlist" data-qtip="Toggle Playlist"></a>

        <div class="cards">
          <div class="song_info card" data-card="song_info">

            <div class="song_actions clearfix">
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Share');" class="share" data-command="share" data-qtip="Share"></a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Download');" data-command="download" data-qtip="Download" class="download"></a>
              <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Favorite');" class="thumb" data-command="recommend" data-qtip="Favorite"></a>
            </div>
            <a href="#" data-role="link"><img data-role="image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /></a>
            <h3 data-role="title"></h3>
            <a href="#" data-role="link">
              <h4 data-role="artist"></h4>
            </a>
            <div class="progress_slider_wrap">
              <div class="player_slider progress_slider">
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress_thumb small"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="time_progress extra_ui" style="word-break: normal !important;">12:123</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="discover_music card" data-card="discover_music">
            <p>Not listening to anything?</p>
            <p>Try one of the <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Discover');" data-command="discover">ReverbNation Channels</a></p>
          </div>

          <div class="feedback card active" data-card="feedback">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="player_song_control" id="player_control">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Prev');" class="btn_prev" data-command="prev"></a>
          <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Play');" class="btn_play" data-command="play"></a>
          <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Pause');" class="btn_pause" data-command="pause" style="display:none;"></a>
          <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Next');" class="btn_next" data-command="next"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="player_slider volume_slider">
          <a href="javascript:trackEvent('V3 Footer Data','Click','Mute');" data-command="mute" class="volume_btn extra_ui"></a>
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress_thumb big"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="footer_content_right" id="docked_footer_content_right">
      <div id="rabbit_hole_controls" class="footer_content_right_profile rabbit_hole_enabled">
        <center>
          <a href="#" id="rabbit-hole-wat">Wat</a>
          <a href="#" class="rabbit-hole-button" id="engage_rabbit_hole">Rabbit Hole</a>
          <a href="#" class="rabbit-hole-button" id="go_deeper">Go deeper</a> <br/>
          <a href="#" id="what_is_rabbit_hole">What's This?</a>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div id="rabbit_hole_tooltip" style="display: none"></div>

      <script language="Javascript">
        Reverb.playerReady(function() {
          var $tooltip = $j('#rabbit_hole_tooltip'),
            timeout_id;

          $tooltip.bind('display-tooltip', function(e, message) {
            $tooltip.html(message);

            $tooltip.trigger('tooltip-show');
            clearTimeout(timeout_id);

            timeout_id = setTimeout(function() {
              $tooltip.trigger('tooltip-hide');
            }, 10000)
          });

          $tooltip.bind('tooltip-show', function(e) {
            $tooltip.stop(true, true, true).
            animate({
              bottom: "-=10",
              opacity: 'show'
            });
          });

          $tooltip.bind('tooltip-hide', function(e) {
            $tooltip.stop(true, true, true).
            animate({
              bottom: "+=10",
              opacity: 'hide'
            });
          });

          $tooltip.click(function(e) {
            var info = MusicPlayer.getInstance().getCurrentSong()
            if (info && info.link) {
              Reverb.Navigate.go_to_page_url(info.link)
            }
            $tooltip.trigger('tooltip-hide');
          })

          $j('#rabbit-hole-wat').hover(function(e) {
            if ($tooltip.html() != "") {
              $tooltip.trigger('tooltip-show');
            }
          }, function(e) {
            $tooltip.trigger('tooltip-hide');
          });

          function recommendationTextFor(hash, current_song) {
            var reason = "Playing <em>" + current_song.artist + "</em> because";
            switch (hash.type) {
              case 'direct':
                reason += " they were recommended by <em>" + $j.escapeHTML(hash.name) + "</em>";
                break;

              case 'show_bill':
                reason += " they played a show with <em>" + $j.escapeHTML(hash.name) + "</em>" +
                  " on " + $j.escapeHTML(hash.latest_show_date) + ' in ' + $j.escapeHTML(hash.latest_show_location);
                break;

              case 'featured_artist':
                reason += " they're a featured artist";
                break;

              default:
                reason += " it's awesome";
                break;
            }

            if (hash.reason != null) {
              return $j.escapeHTML(hash.reason) + ". " + reason;
            } else {
              return reason;
            }
          }

          MusicPlayer.getInstance().bind('playlist_updated', function(e, player) {
            if ($j('#rabbit_hole_controls').hasClass('rabbit_hole_enabled')) {
              $j('#music_player .player_queue_item:last').addClass('in_rabbit_hole');
            }
          });

          MusicPlayer.getInstance().bind('song_play', function(e, player) {
            var current_song = player && player.getCurrentSong();
            if (current_song == null) {
              // Hopefully means we got the thing cleared
              $j('#rabbit_hole_controls').removeClass('rabbit_hole_enabled');
              $j('#rabbit_hole_tooltip').html('');
              Reverb.RabbitHoleCache = {};
              return;
            }
            if (Reverb.RabbitHoleCache[parseInt(current_song.id, 10)] != null) {
              $tooltip.trigger('display-tooltip', recommendationTextFor(Reverb.RabbitHoleCache[parseInt(current_song.id, 10)], current_song))
            }
          });
        })


        $j(function($) {

          var goToCurrentArtist = function() {
            // wee need a little delay to be sure the playlist is actually loaded before making any redirect
            // not the ideal solution, but it doesn't require a beautiful reaper
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              var info = MusicPlayer.getInstance().getCurrentSong()
              if (info && info.link) {
                Reverb.Navigate.go_to_page_url(info.link)
              }
            })

          }

          $('#engage_rabbit_hole').click(function(e) {
            var current_po;
            if ((CURRENT_PAGE_OBJECT || '').match(/artist_/)) {
              current_po = CURRENT_PAGE_OBJECT;
            } else {
              current_po = ''
            }

            trackEvent('V3 Footer Data', 'Click', 'Rabbit Hole');

            $.ajax('/c/audio_player/rabbit_hole_now/' + current_po, {
              type: 'get',
              beforeSend: function() {
                $j('#rabbit_hole_tooltip').trigger('display-tooltip', 'Loading…');
              },
              complete: goToCurrentArtist
            });
            return false;
          });

          $('#go_deeper').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var player = MusicPlayer.getInstance();

            trackEvent('V3 Footer Data', 'Click', 'Go Deeper');

            if (player.playingIndex < player.playlist.length - 1) {
              player.sendCommand('next');
              goToCurrentArtist()
            }

          });

          $('#what_is_rabbit_hole').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal_open('/audio_player/modal/rabbit_hole_modal')
            trackEvent('V3 Footer Data', 'Click', 'What Is Rabbit Hole');
          });

          Reverb.RabbitHoleCache = Reverb.RabbitHoleCache || {};
        });
      </script>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer_marketing_wrap">
    <div id="footer_marketing" class="standard_footer_marketing standard_typography"></div>
  </div>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
      $("#player_about").qtip()

      var $form = $("#custom_channel_form")

      $("#music_player select").chosen().change(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $form.center($form.parent())
        }, 0)

      })

      $form.center($form.parent())

      Reverb.playerReady(function() {

        var load_timeout;
        /* - No longer tied to profile page, will use server-side to check session cookie -
       var songs_container = $("#profile_songs_container"), current_song_id, load_timeout
 
       songs_container.delegate(".standard_play_button:not(.playing)","click", function(){
       current_song_id = $(this).attr("data-song-id")
       window.clearTimeout(load_timeout)
       })
       */
        MusicPlayer.getInstance().bind("playlist_updated", function fn(ev, player) {

          var song = player.getCurrentSong();
          /* - No longer tied to profile page, will use server-side to check session cookie -
         if(songs_container.is(":not(:visible)")){
         // detach the event listener, as the user left the original profile page
         player.unbind("playlist_updated", fn)
         }else if(song){
         // if the current sound might not be the one the user is listening to.
         // In order to be sure we're tracking the correct data, we have to check that the current song in the playlist is actually the one the user clicked on
 
         if(current_song_id+"" == song.id+""){
         current_song_id = false;
         */
          window.clearTimeout(load_timeout);
          var check_loaded = function() {
            if (song && player.currentSound && player.currentSound.getLoaded()) { // the load percentage is > 0
              //alert('before incrementing lp_song_plays');
              $.get("/artist/increment_lp_song_plays", {
                song_id: song.id
              });
            } else {
              load_timeout = window.setTimeout(check_loaded, 100);
            }
          }
          check_loaded();
          /*  }
           }*/
        });
      });

    })
  </script>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like they're using AJAX and the History API to handle page requests.

Comment: So how complicated is something like that to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are refering to, is a single page website. They are not changing pages but change the look of the one page with javascript and ajax requests. That's why the player keeps playing.

Comment: If that was the case wouldn't the URL be static?

Comment: Like BenM said before, i think they are using the html5 history api. With that, you can change the url without triggering the browser to load the site. Here is an article about the api: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: On the demo if you refresh the page, you end up with an invalid url. I'm assuming there must be a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: That's something your server has to handle. With tomcat for example, you can use wildcards to map a servlet or jsp to urls:
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/history/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

So the server will give you the same html document regardless of the url and you can do the rest in the browser using javascript.